# no rows selected on sqlplus using bash

Tags: sql, bash, sqlplus

I'm trying to get a variable from my table in sql. Refer my script below:

```
  FILE_LIST=$(sqlplus -s idmp_stg/idmp_stg@DTPMPDR07_SUDB <<EOF  
  set echo off heading off                                       
  SELECT Column_B                                                
  FROM anum_calltype                                             
  WHERE Column_A = 2500;                                         
  exit;                                                          
  EOF)
```

but i this is what i get

```
  no rows selected
```

This is my database table:

```
 select * from anum_calltype

 +-------+---------+---
 |Column_A  | Column_B|
 +-------+---------+---
 | 1000     | 2020    |
 | 2500     | 99102   |
 | 2020     | 99120   |
 +-------+---------+---
```

This is my expected output:

```
 SELECT Column_B          
 FROM anum_calltype       
 WHERE Column_A = 2500;

 | Column_B |
 ------------
    99102
```

In Bash:

```
   99102
```

Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Looks as though it *should* work. What are the datatypes of `Column_A` and `Column_B`? Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database?

Comment: varchar(6) for both. Yes, I am sure that's the correct database.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any trailing spaces in `Column_B`?